# Code inside the catch block is being executed even after successful login and completion of try block

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, bcrypt

```
Front end(login.js)
const login = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = await loginUser({
        email,
        password,
      });
      console.log("Login response", response);
      if (response.data) {
        console.log("Login response", response.data);
        console.log("Save user in redux and local storage and then redirect");
      }
      router.push("/");
    } catch (e) {
      toast.error("Something went wrong, try again");
    }
  };

Backend(login.js)
export const login = async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  let user = await User.findOne({ email }).exec();
  if (user) {
    const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (validPassword) {
      res.status(200).send("Successfully logged in");
    } else {
      res.status(401).send("Invalid password provided");
    }
  } else {
    res.status(401).send("User with that email address doesn't exist");
  }
};
```

What is the reason why I am seeing that toast appearing inside of  that catch block? The login is successful but I also get something went wrong toast popup. Is there better way to handle the error codes or something?

Comment: What does `router.push("/")` do? Does that perhaps raise an exception?

Comment: Try logging the error by `console.log(e)`, if possible kindly paste the logs as well.